# How to get dynamic maximum value of integer based on the number of decimal places

Tags: c#, math, logic

I have a dynamic data of 0001, since it is dynamic it can change based on the data given. it could be 01 or 001 or 0001. to derive this value i have a code of

```
            var placeholderValue = 4; //number can be dynamic. 
            var intFormattedValue = String.Format($"{{0:D{palceholderValue}}}", 1);
            var parasedValue =  Int32.Parse(intFormattedValue); //output 0001
```

if the placeholderValue above is 4, the output would be 0001 if it is 3 then 001 then if 2 01.

What i want to get is if the value is 0001 then it would return 9999 
if the value is 001 then 999 if 01 then 99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `Math.Pow` method for 10 power and some calculation get the maximum value

```
Math.Pow(10, placeholderValue) - 1
```

Comment: Exactly the solution I need.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new string directly

```
string placeHolderValue = "0001";
string output = new string('9',placeHolderValue.Length);
//if an int is needed
int outInt = Int32.Parse(output);
```